# error implementing a multivariate regressor neural network in keras

Tags: neural-network, keras, regression, loss-function

I am trying to implement a dummy multivariate regressor neural network in keras. The input is 12-dimensional while the output is 2 dimensional

My source code is attached

```
import pandas as pd 
from keras.models import Sequential 
from keras.layers import Dense 
from keras.layers import Activation 
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline 
import numpy as np 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
from keras import losses

dataframe=pd.read_csv("housing.csv", delim_whitespace=True, header=None)       
dataset=dataframe.values 
X=dataset[:,0:12] 
Y=dataset[:,11:13]  

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.33,  random_state=42) 

l1=Dense(12, input_dim=11, activation='relu', use_bias=False) 
l2=Dense(24, activation='relu', use_bias=False) 
l3=Dense(12, activation='relu', use_bias=False) 
l4=Dense(2, activation='linear', use_bias=False)

model=Sequential([l1,l2,l3,l4]) 

print("Printing model summary \n") 
print(model.summary())

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam') 
model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_split=0.2, epochs=10, batch_size=10)
```

When I try to fit the model. I get the following error

> Error when checking input: expected dense_129_input to have shape
>   (11,) but got array with shape (12,)

Why am I getting this error?

In a similar problem on regression (univariate) I was getting similar error but when I changed the loss function,  I was able to fit the model. In this case, I am not able to fit the model irrespective of the loss function that I choose.

Any help?

I was following the discussion at [Multi-dimensional regression with Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43985082/multi-dimensional-regression-with-keras)

Comment: You say that your input is 12-dimensional yet you specify `input_dim=11` when specifying your model. Why not `input_dim=12`?

Comment: thank you @sdcbr for helping me. Now I am able to fit my model